# Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server: Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, odbc

I am aware this question has been asked before. I have been following the extensive troubleshooting steps at [MSQL Tips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2340/resolving-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-errors/) as well as every answer I can find on Google. I am really stumped.

The error is as follows:

[image]

I cannot seem to get past this error. Every time I install/uninstall MS SQL Server I receive the same error. I have even performed a hard reset of the laptop removing even the BIOS information but I still get the same error. I have discovered that installs of MS SQL Server are concurrent so this perhaps explains it.

I even set up a virtual machine running Windows 7 to debug and got the exact same message. **The application can be run on a different workstation and works perfectly.** It seems the issue is something hard coded on to my computer.

Comment: Have you tried OSQL -L or SQLCMD -L to see if the server is responding?

Answer (score 6):

**Not knowing the full details of your issue by your question try the following:**

**Option 1:**

Temporarily disable Windows Firewall and test your SQL script once more:

[image]

**Option 2:**

Make sure NetBIOS is enabled in the TCP/IP settings of the network adapter you are using:

[image]

**Option 3:**

Ensure that SQL Server protocols are enabled through SQL Server Configuration Manager:

[image]

**Option 4:**

Try a combination of two or more options above.

Answer (score 1):

You may get this type of error due to using small (-s) instead of capital (-S)...
please check the parameter character by changing upper/ lower case...

I had already faced this type of issue and resolved by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Windows 7, SQL Server 2014 Express, call sqlcmd from a bat file, named pipes error 53), it was a combination of:

1. Enabling Named Pipes and TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration Manager\SQL Network Configuraton, as suggested in @Sting's answer above
2. Using the correct Server Name in

   ```
   sqlcmd -S <ServerName> -i <.sql file>
   ```

   You can get this string from the Connect to Database Engine pop-up in MSSQL Server Management Studio, or by querying the database:

   ```
   SELECT @@servername
   ```

The command line:

```
    sqlcmd -L
```

was no help in this case, as it still lists a blank line, even after I got the batch file working.

Answer (score 0):

If using localdb, put `(localdb)\` before server instance name.
I should particularly stress on using a back-slash `\`.

(BTW, experiences are only useful when we remember them, unlike me re-experiencing and re-finding the solution after 2 years...)