# The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

I'm running into a problem when trying to run any of the jobs created by Ola's script:

> The process could not be created for step 1 of job
>   0x19DAD4A7019FB04D9C984027FCA2F4E3 (reason: The system cannot find the
>   file specified).  The step failed.

I've made sure that sqlcmd is in the PATH environment variable, and I've also put the sql agent service account in local administrators to make sure it isn't a permission issue.

When I log into the server locally with an account that has local admin rights and sysadmin on the sql server and try to run sqlcmd.exe I get the following:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Named Pipes
>   Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. .
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Login timeout
>   expired.
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : A
>   network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while 
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and i f SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online..

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/143642/112253

Comment: Same result after doing all three recommendations.

Comment: I should also note that this is not the default instance. When I try "sqlcmd -S localhost\InstanceName the connection is successful.

Answer (score 3):

This ended up being a permission issue to the path where sqlcmd resides.

Answer (score 1):

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. .
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and i f SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..

To fix the error above, log into the SQL Server and open up the SQL Server Configuration Manager. Navigate to *SQL Server Network Configuration* -> *Protocols for [Instance Name]*. Right-Click and enable **Named Pipes**.

Enabling the Named Pipes protocol will require a restart of the appropriate SQL Server Database instance service in order to take effect.

Once the SQL Server Database Engine service is restarted, you will be able to run SQLCMD.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ola Scripts to create the jobs and changing the job type from CmdExec to T-SQL fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar error

> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. The process could not be created for step 1 of job 0x0E4E0C4738AF0D4C8A1F629146CE1EFE (reason: The system cannot find the file specified).  The step failed.

I had previously updated my Ola scripts and had not recreated the jobs.  I did copy over the new scripts within the jobs but overlooked changing the job type from **CmdExec** to **T-SQL**.